# paypal adaptive payment API custom page style

Tags: api, rest, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

There is a paypal setup with multiple pageStyles defined.

Using the "Classic API", the Adaptive Payments is wired up with the the post request json similar to:

```
{

 "requestEnvelope": {
    "errorLanguage": "en_US"
  },
  "actionType": "PAY",
  "receiverList": {"receiver" => receiver_list},
  "currencyCode": "USD,
  "feesPayer": "EACHRECEIVER",
  "memo": "Some memo message",
  "cancelUrl": "cancel.com",
  "returnUrl": "thankyou.com",
  "ipnNotificationUrl": "ipn.com"
}
```

This post request goes to:

```
https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay
```

With headers as follows:

```
{
  "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID": "my_security_id",
  "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD": "my_security_password",
  "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE": "my_security_signature",
  "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON",
  "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON",
  "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID": "my_application_id"
}
```

I checked out the Adaptive Payment API here: [Adaptive Payment PAY](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/)

It doesnt have any option to specify page style like in the REST API here: [Custom Page Style In REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPCustomizing/#id0863B0L805Z)

Is there a way to specify `Page Style` via the Adaptive Payment API?